# Oracle Apex Custom Authentication Error - 'MY_AUTHENTICATION' IS NOT A PROCEDURE

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, custom-authentication

Excuse my naivety but I've been fighting this issue for a few hours now with no progress and I'm lost as to what I'm missing. I'm quite new to Oracle and still getting to grips with a lot of the custom functionality.

I'm trying to write a function (following the guidelines on the APEX interface) regarding validating login credentials using a custom authentication scheme for my application.

The guidelines state:

> Specify the name of the function that will verify the user's username and password, after they were entered on a login page. If you enter nothing, you allow any username/password to succeed. The function itself can be defined in the authentication's 'PL/SQL Code' textarea, within a package or as a stored function.
>   This function must return a boolean to the login procedure that calls it. It has 2 input parameters 'p_username' and 'p_password' that can be used to access the values an end user entered on the login page.
>   Examples
>   Enter the following code in the 'PL/SQL Code' textarea

```
function my_authentication (
    p_username in varchar2,
    p_password in varchar2 )
    return boolean
is
    l_user my_users.user_name%type := upper(p_username);
    l_pwd  my_users.password%type;
    l_id   my_users.id%type;
begin
    select id  , password
      into l_id, l_pwd
      from my_users
     where user_name = l_user;

    return l_pwd = rawtohex(sys.dbms_crypto.hash (
                       sys.utl_raw.cast_to_raw(p_password||l_id||l_user),
                       sys.dbms_crypto.hash_sh512 ));
exception
    when NO_DATA_FOUND then return false;
end;
```

and `my_authentication` as `Authentication Function`.

The function I have wrote is not even as complex as I'm not encrypting pwd etc at present to try and just get the thing working

```
function my_authentication (p_username in varchar2,p_password in varchar2 )
    return boolean
is
    valid NUMBER;
    returnvalid BOOLEAN;
begin
    begin
        select 1
        into valid
        from users u
        where u.sys_user.login = lower(p_username) AND u.sys_user.password = p_password;    
    exception
        when NO_DATA_FOUND then valid := 0;
    end;
    returnvalid := valid=1;
    RETURN returnvalid;
end;
```

To clarify the users table is made up of 3 fields and the one storing the data I want to validate is `sys_user` (it is an object type with 5 fields: `id`, `fname`, `lname`, `login`, `password`).

When I set the Authentication Function Name to `my_authentication` and attempt to login I get the following error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00221: 'MY_AUTHENTICATION' is not a procedure or is undefined 
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I'm assuming this is coming from where I have changed

```
apex_authentication.login(    
    p_username => :P101_USERNAME,
    p_password => :P101_PASSWORD
);
```

to

```
my_authentication(
    p_username => :P101_USERNAME,
    p_password => :P101_PASSWORD
);
```

under the `Processing`->`Process`->`Login`->`Source` of the Apex interface. What I can't seem to find a solution too is why it is requesting a procedure when the custom Authentication Scheme configuration page clearly asks for a function returning a boolean which is what I have created. I know it states that a login procedure will call it but I have assumed this is the APEX interface initiating a validation procedure where by it looks for my method?

Any help is very much appreciated and I hope I've enough detail to make sense of my issue

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have changed the page process code, it should remain as:

```
apex_authentication.login(    
    p_username => :P101_USERNAME,
    p_password => :P101_PASSWORD
);
```

This performs some logic that **includes** dynamically running the authentication function you have specified in the authentication scheme.

Comment: Thanks Tony. I had changed it back earlier and it still wouldnt login but my session expired and have just changed this back again and its working perfectly now